# How to replace text that contains round brackets (parentheses) with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

```
oldvalue = "RGB = (255,000,255,000)"
newvalue = "RGB = (255,255,000,000)"
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt", 
                    Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt"), 
                                    oldvalue, 
                                    newvalue));
```

this is not replacing with the new value.

But it worked with

```
oldvalue = "RGB 1"
newvalue = "RGB 0"
```

Comment: Are you sure there are _exact_ matches of `RGB = (255,000,255,000)` in `Abc.txt`?

Comment: brackets in regex have special meaning so it would confuse it

Comment: @Anton yes there is a exact match of RGB = (255,000,255,000) in ABC.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the string you want to replace is a row string, don't use `Regex.Replace` but `String.Replace`:

```
string oldvalue = "RGB = (255,000,255,000)";
string newvalue = "RGB = (255,255,000,000)";
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt", 
            File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt").Replace( 
                            oldvalue, 
                            newvalue));
```

Comment: What do you mean by row string ?

Comment: @DevDroneBhowmik well, I mean that the string you what to find doesn't require a regex to be found

Comment: Then when should i use regex ?

Comment: @DevDroneBhowmik you should use regex when you have complex patterns. Here you want to find `RGB = (255,000,255,000)` then, just search for it. If you would have wanted to find all RGB colors, you may have use a regex like [`RGB = \((?:(?:\d{1,3},?){4})\)`](https://regex101.com/r/cS0uL8/1).

Answer (score 0):

Since `oldvalue` contains characters which have special meaning in regex like `(` and `)` you should escape them with `\` character .

```
oldvalue = "RGB = \\(255,000,255,000\\)"
//or oldvalue = @"RGB = \(255,000,255,000\)"
newvalue = "RGB = (255,255,000,000)"
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt", 
                    Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt"), 
                                    oldvalue, 
                                    newvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try smth like this:

```
regexp = "(.*)\((.*)\)(.*)"
newvalue = "RGB = (255,255,000,000)"
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt",      
    Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\devdrone\\Desktop\\Abc.txt"), 
                                    regexp, 
                                    newvalue));
```